# RewriteRule if first character is question mark

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a problem with my .htaccess file.

At the moment I use the following script for every request under the subdir /lp:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /lp
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*\.(jpg|css|js|gif|png)$ [NC]
RewriteRule . index.php
```

If someone uses an URL like the following

```
www.website.com/?1FOOBAR23
```

I would also like to redirect to the subdirectory /lp with the same rule as above. But only if the URL starts with a question mark followed by a number and 6-8 other chars. How could I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need this rule in site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^[a-z0-9]{6,}$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ ip/index.php [L]
```

Comment: @anabhava: Thank you very much for your answer! I'm still trying to figure out how to make it work but I think I'm really close. The RewriteCond seems to work now. Maybe the RewriteRule is not correct. I added this content to the .htaccess in the root dir:

`RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^[0-9]{1,3}[A-Z0-9]{6}$
RewriteRule ^/?$ lp/index.php [L]`

Comment: Sorry, it was my fault. The routing of my applications seems to make problems. The RewriteRule seems to work perfectly! Thank you a lot for your help!